# Python Comprehensions troubleshooting

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, list-comprehension

I have problems to set up correctly my if statement.

This is my code:

```
def task_13():
    Main_meal=['Meat','Cheese','Fish']
    addons=['Potatoes','Rice','Salad']
    my_meal=[(x+y) for x in Main_meal for y in addons if (x+y)!= 'FishRice' and 'CheeseRice']
    print(my_meal)
```

My question is why Python filter out the 'CheeseRice' when is it stated there but only filter out the 'FishRice' option.

This is my output:

```
['MeatPotatoes', 'MeatRice', 'MeatSalad', 'CheesePotatoes', 'CheeseRice', 'CheeseSalad', 'FishPotatoes', 'FishSalad']
```

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the official [reference on Python operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), note that `and` is lower precedence than `!=`, so the `!=` is evaluated first. Also `and` is a simple operator that takes the booleans on either side and returns a boolean representing their logical AND, it doesn't do what you tried to make it do.

Instead of

```
if (x+y)!= 'FishRice' and 'CheeseRice'
```

you need:

```
if (x+y)!= 'FishRice' and (x+y) != 'CheeseRice'
```

or alternatively

```
if (x+y) not in ('FishRice', 'CheeseRice')
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand where I make mistake now